# Is there a way to calculate 32 bit fraction of the second?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get 64 bits (8 bytes) of python hex time stamps(current time/time of day).

```
new0 = hex(int(time.time()))[2:]
new0
'60cc8697'   <--- (only 32 bits of MSB bits)
```

Expected format (fraction of seconds): (32 bits of LSB bits)
60cc839600000000

Tried:
Using python version :python3.8

```
new0 = hex(long(time.time())

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'long' is not defined
```

Comment: The error message is telling you it doesn't know what `long()` is. Where does `long()` come from? Do you mean `int()`? You can't just make up/guess/hope that a function exists - you'll only get errors when you do that.

Comment: Timestamps typically only  have 64 bits total, and the upper 32 bits will all be 0 until sometime in 2038. Also, `long` only exists in Python 2; there is a single `int` type in Python 3. (Even in Python 2, `long` was an implementation detail that didn't really need to be exposed, as any `int` value would automatically promoted to `long` as necessary.)

Comment: @barny, "long" keyword not valid in python3.x, This is used for long integers in python2. So, I tried "int" to support for "long integer". My actual requirement is to get fraction of seconds in hex format.

Comment: @chepner, Yes, This is a case where I need to (or try to) get fraction of seconds. time.time() will give fraction of values (after .) for accuracy. That needs to be converted to hex timestamps.

Comment: Woulod UTC time stamp satisfy your purposes i.e. [Get UTC Timestamp](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-utc-timestamp-in-python/)?

Comment: @chepner, Actually this timestamp compared to a pcap (packet)- protocol specific timestamp. Ex. 60b733c828a23c08, Just trying to get diff of two timestamps(pcap and timeofday)

Comment: @DarrylG, will come back with the tries.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to work with strings, just a bit mask.

```
>>> hex(int(time.time()) & 0xffffffff000000000)
'0x0'
```

However, no timestamp before 2038 will have any of the upper 32 bits set. Perhaps you want the upper 48 bits (i.e., the upper 16 bits of the 32 bits actually in use):

```
>>> hex(int(time.time()) & 0xffffffffffff0000)
'0x60cc0000'
```

Or maybe (for some reason) you want to simply pad the timestamp with 32 bits of 0s. You can do that with a left shift.

```
>>> hex(int(time.time()) << 32)
'0x60cc8e4200000000'
```